# How to increase the number of submenu items displayed in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am trying to get rid of the menu fold (grouping in "more" sub-menu) in SugarCRM or at least increase number of sub-menu items before folding occurs. I have searched code so far and can't find where this is implemented.
[image: submenu folding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but found a setting in config.php `default_max_tabs = '7'` which increases the number before folding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes currently the only way is to override this config value in config_override.php and define default_max_tabs setting. This is available only since SugarCRM 6.2